# Evenly spacing views within adjacent layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on the controls for a game, and require part of the control panel (gray in the figure below) to change dynamically, either showing a single canvas (left) or 5 buttons (right). The border between the lower-row views should always be positioned at exactly the same x-position as the border between the buttons on the upper row, as shown. At the same time, all twelve upper buttons should be scaled and distributed evenly.

[image: Layout including canvas (left) and buttons (right)]

I've considered several approaches, but as of yet none do all of what I want:

- Using two LinearLayouts, one for each row of controls: reliably aligning the borders seems to be impossible, and replacing part of the layout is difficult at best.
- Using a TableLayout: again, replacing a portion of the layout is difficult.
- Using a RelativeLayout: resizing and aligning buttons independently of the screen size doesn't seem possible

Any suggestions for an alternative method, or on how to make one of the above approaches work? It would also be nice if there were some way to animate the change of views, i.e. sliding in the buttons from the left over the canvas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close this question: I have solved the problem by writing a custom layout class that places and sizes the child views without heeding the measured size of the children. Effectively this gives me the behavior of a linear layout with layout weights, but is more deterministic with border placement.

A ViewAnimator is used to switch between the Canvas and the Buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I've done this several weeks ago. What I did is to make use of this property of `View` object: `"Visibility"`. So that means at a fixed position, I can set any `View` to display on to, not depending on any type of `Layout`, it can be `Visibility.GONE`, `Visibility.VISIBLE` or `Visibility.INVISIBLE`.

In my app, I used `RelativeLayout` to set relative position to the right side `TextView`.
Give it a try :)

Comment: While this can be used to choose which view/s is/are displayed, my major difficulty is in getting the alignment of the views correct, i.e. evenly spaced buttons on top and views on the bottom that align with the buttons on top.

Comment: make them having equal size, `RelativeLayout` will make them align nicely.

Comment: No matter what I try, RelativeLayout will not scale the buttons to fill the entire screen width (unless of course I specify the exact number of pixels for my device, which breaks as soon as the screen resolution changes), nor can I get the top row of buttons to have the same height as the bottom row. Any suggestions for how to get the scaling correct?